# How to create Map in LambdaJ where value is Collection?

Tags: java, lambdaj

I know how to make `Map<String, Car>` but how to make `Map<String, List<Car>>` in lambdaj?

This is code I want to write in LambdaJ:

```
Map<String, List<Car>> driverCarsMap = new HashMap<String, List<Car>>();
for (Car car : cars)
{
    String driver = car.getDriver();
    if (!driverCarsMap.containsKey(driver))
            driverCarsMap.put(driver, new ArrayList<Car>());

    driverCarsMap.get(driver).add(car);
}
```

Unfortunately the code:

```
Map<String, List<Car>> driverCarsMap = index(cars, on(Car.class).getDriver());
```

creates the Map, but value is not being extended but overwritten. So, de facto we do note have a List but single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is similar to LambdaJ **index** method. The problem with index is its limitation, its documentation says:

> The former index feature is enough in many cases, but it has at least
>   2 big limitations: it doesn't manage conflicts if 2 or more objects
>   should be indexed on the same key value and it doesn't easily allow to
>   index the objects in a multilevel hierarchy.
>
> To overcome these constraints lambdaj provides a feature to
>   (optionally hierarchically) group objects on the value of their
>   properties. As usual the preferred (statically typed) way in lambdaj
>   to choose an object's property is via the on construct, so to group a
>   List of Persons based on their ages it is sufficient to write:
>
> Group group = group(meAndMyFriends, by(on(Person.class).getAge()));

So, what you have to use is LambdaJ **groups**. For your example, it would be:

```
Group<Car> group = group(cars, by(on(Car.class).getDriver()));
```

You can take a look at grouping items here:
https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures#Grouping_items

Comment: hmm thanks for explanation well, it seems that I cannot create such a Map. What I need is to have Map instead of Group because of already existing interfaces

Comment: If you want to use LambdaJ for the code you posted then "group" is the answer. But, if you then need a post processing on groups you can create a parser to transform it. Btw, if you like functional approach you can use Guava Function and Collection2.transform